# combine two vectors in correct order

Tags: r

I have two vectors for example:

```
  v1 <- c("a","j","d")
  v2 <- c("book","tree","river")
```

I would like to combine the two vectors keeping the same order:

```
  v3 <- c("a","book","j","tree","d","river")
```

I tried:

```
  c(v1,v2)
```

but the ordering is wrong

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `c(rbind(v1, v2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v1 <- c("a","j","d")
v2 <- c("book","tree","river")
c(rbind(v1,v2))
# [1] "a"     "book"  "j"     "tree"  "d"     "river"
```